# How do i Swipe selected grid image in Full Screen

Tags: android, android-viewpager, swipe, photoswipe

i created a grid-view image app, and i want to show selected image in image swipe.

actually i implemented image swipe in my app **but** the problem is image swipe starts from 1st image not from selected image.

**example:**

if i choose 3rd image image swipe should starts from 3rd image not from 1st image.

**my code:**

**MainActivity.java**

```
package com.td.gridview;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.view.ViewGroup.LayoutParams;
import android.view.ViewTreeObserver;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
import android.widget.GridView;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.RelativeLayout;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    private GridView photoGrid;
    private int mPhotoSize, mPhotoSpacing;
    private ImageAdapter imageAdapter;

    // Some items to add to the GRID
    private static final String[] CONTENT = new String[] 
            { 
            "pic1",
            "pic2",
            "pic3",
            "pic4",
            "pic5",
            "pic6",
            "pic7",
            "pic8",
            "pic9"
            };
    static final int[] ICONS = new int[] 
            { 
            R.drawable.pic1,
            R.drawable.pic2,
            R.drawable.pic3,
            R.drawable.pic4,
            R.drawable.pic5,
            R.drawable.pic6,
            R.drawable.pic7,
            R.drawable.pic8,
            R.drawable.pic9
            };

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        // get the photo size and spacing
        mPhotoSize = getResources().getDimensionPixelSize(R.dimen.photo_size);
        mPhotoSpacing = getResources().getDimensionPixelSize(R.dimen.photo_spacing);

        // initialize image adapter
        imageAdapter = new ImageAdapter();

        photoGrid = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.albumGrid);

        //start sent image to full screen             

        /**
         * On Click event for Single Gridview Item
         * */
        photoGrid.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View v,
                    int position, long id) {

                // Sending image id to FullScreenActivity
                Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), SwipeActivity.class);
                // passing array index
                i.putExtra("id", position);
                startActivity(i);
            }
        });
        //end sent image to full screen

        // set image adapter to the GridView
        photoGrid.setAdapter(imageAdapter);

        // get the view tree observer of the grid and set the height and numcols dynamically
        photoGrid.getViewTreeObserver().addOnGlobalLayoutListener(new ViewTreeObserver.OnGlobalLayoutListener() {
            @Override
            public void onGlobalLayout() {
                if (imageAdapter.getNumColumns() == 0) {
                    final int numColumns = (int) Math.floor(photoGrid.getWidth() / (mPhotoSize + mPhotoSpacing));
                    if (numColumns > 0) {
                        final int columnWidth = (photoGrid.getWidth() / numColumns) - mPhotoSpacing;
                        imageAdapter.setNumColumns(numColumns);
                        imageAdapter.setItemHeight(columnWidth);

                    }
                }
            }
        });
    }

    // ///////// ImageAdapter class /////////////////
    public class ImageAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
        private LayoutInflater mInflater;
        private int mItemHeight = 0;
        private int mNumColumns = 0;
        private RelativeLayout.LayoutParams mImageViewLayoutParams;

        public ImageAdapter() {
            mInflater = (LayoutInflater) getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            mImageViewLayoutParams = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                    LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
        }

        public int getCount() {
            return CONTENT.length;
        }

        // set numcols
        public void setNumColumns(int numColumns) {
            mNumColumns = numColumns;
        }

        public int getNumColumns() {
            return mNumColumns;
        }

        // set photo item height
        public void setItemHeight(int height) {
            if (height == mItemHeight) {
                return;
            }
            mItemHeight = height;
            mImageViewLayoutParams = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, mItemHeight);
            notifyDataSetChanged();
        }

        public Object getItem(int position) {
            return position;
        }

        public long getItemId(int position) {
            return position;
        }

        public View getView(final int position, View view, ViewGroup parent) {

            if (view == null)
                view = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.photo_item, null);

            ImageView cover = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.cover);
            TextView title = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.title);

            cover.setLayoutParams(mImageViewLayoutParams);

            // Check the height matches our calculated column width
            if (cover.getLayoutParams().height != mItemHeight) {
                cover.setLayoutParams(mImageViewLayoutParams);
            }

            cover.setImageResource(ICONS[position % ICONS.length]);
            title.setText(CONTENT[position % CONTENT.length]);

            return view;
        }
    }

}
```

**SwipeActivity.java**

```
    package com.td.gridview;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.view.PagerAdapter;
import android.support.v4.view.ViewPager;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import com.td.gridview.MainActivity;



public class SwipeActivity extends Activity 
{   

  @Override
  public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.swipe_view);

    int[] icons = MainActivity.ICONS;    

    //get image position

    Intent n = getIntent();
    int position= n.getIntExtra("id", position);

    ViewPager viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.view_pager);    
    ImagePagerAdapter adapter = new ImagePagerAdapter(SwipeActivity.this , MainActivity.ICONS[position]);
    viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);
    viewPager.setCurrentItem(position);
  }

  private class ImagePagerAdapter extends PagerAdapter 
  {
      int[] icons = MainActivity.ICONS;    

    @Override
    public int getCount() 
    {
      return icons.length;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isViewFromObject(View view, Object object) 
    {
      return view == ((ImageView) object);
    }

    @Override
    public Object instantiateItem(ViewGroup container, int position) 
    {
      Context context = SwipeActivity.this;
      ImageView imageView = new ImageView(context);
//      int padding = context.getResources().getDimensionPixelSize(
//          R.dimen.padding_large);
//      imageView.setPadding(padding, padding, padding, padding);
      imageView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER_INSIDE);
      imageView.setImageResource(icons[position]);
      ((ViewPager) container).addView(imageView, 0);
      return imageView;
    }

    @Override
    public void destroyItem(ViewGroup container, int position, Object object) 
    {
      ((ViewPager) container).removeView((ImageView) object);
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**after too much bullshit / errors i finally got the answer and it's very simply...;)**

```
// get intent data
    Intent i = getIntent();

    // Selected image id
    int position = i.getExtras().getInt("id");

ViewPager viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.view_pager);
    ImagePagerAdapter adapter = new ImagePagerAdapter();
    viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);
    viewPager.setCurrentItem(position);
```

**this is the simple answer instead of this code:**

```
ImagePagerAdapter adapter = new ImagePagerAdapter(mContext , icons[position]);
```

**this worked.**

```
viewPager.setCurrentItem(position);
```

**now below is my hole app code:**

**MainActivity.java**

```
package com.td.gridview;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.view.ViewGroup.LayoutParams;
import android.view.ViewTreeObserver;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
import android.widget.GridView;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.RelativeLayout;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {


    private GridView photoGrid;
    private int mPhotoSize, mPhotoSpacing;
    private ImageAdapter imageAdapter;

    // Some items to add to the GRID
    private static final String[] CONTENT = new String[] 
            { 
            "Akon", "Justin Bieber", "AlRight", "Big Sean",
            "Britney Spears", "Hilary", "Micheal Buble", "Akon", "Justin Bieber", "AlRight", "Big Sean",
            "Britney Spears", "Hilary", "Micheal Buble", "Britney Spears", "Hilary", "Micheal Buble", "Akon",
            "Justin Bieber", "AlRight", "Big Sean", "Britney Spears", "Hilary", "Micheal Buble", "Akon",
            "Justin Bieber", "AlRight", "Big Sean", "Britney Spears", "Hilary", "Micheal Buble", "Akon",
            "Justin Bieber", "AlRight", "Big Sean", "Britney Spears", "Hilary", "Micheal Buble", "Britney Spears",
            "Hilary", "Micheal Buble", "Akon", "Justin Bieber", "AlRight", "Big Sean", "Britney Spears", "Hilary",
            "Micheal Buble" 
            };
    static final int[] ICONS = new int[] 
            { 
            R.drawable.cover_akon, R.drawable.cover_justin,
            R.drawable.cover_alright, R.drawable.cover_big_sean, R.drawable.cover_britney, R.drawable.cover_hilary,
            R.drawable.cover_mb, R.drawable.cover_akon, R.drawable.cover_justin, R.drawable.cover_alright,
            R.drawable.cover_big_sean, R.drawable.cover_britney, R.drawable.cover_hilary, R.drawable.cover_mb,
            R.drawable.cover_britney, R.drawable.cover_hilary, R.drawable.cover_mb, R.drawable.cover_akon,
            R.drawable.cover_justin, R.drawable.cover_alright, R.drawable.cover_big_sean, R.drawable.cover_britney,
            R.drawable.cover_hilary, R.drawable.cover_mb, R.drawable.cover_akon, R.drawable.cover_justin,
            R.drawable.cover_alright, R.drawable.cover_big_sean, R.drawable.cover_britney, R.drawable.cover_hilary,
            R.drawable.cover_mb, R.drawable.cover_akon, R.drawable.cover_justin, R.drawable.cover_alright,
            R.drawable.cover_big_sean, R.drawable.cover_britney, R.drawable.cover_hilary, R.drawable.cover_mb,
            R.drawable.cover_britney, R.drawable.cover_hilary, R.drawable.cover_mb, R.drawable.cover_akon,
            R.drawable.cover_justin, R.drawable.cover_alright, R.drawable.cover_big_sean, R.drawable.cover_britney,
            R.drawable.cover_hilary, R.drawable.cover_mb 
            };

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);



        // get the photo size and spacing
        mPhotoSize = getResources().getDimensionPixelSize(R.dimen.photo_size);
        mPhotoSpacing = getResources().getDimensionPixelSize(R.dimen.photo_spacing);

        // initialize image adapter
        imageAdapter = new ImageAdapter();

        photoGrid = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.albumGrid);

        //start sent image to full screen             

        /**
         * On Click event for Single Gridview Item
         * */
        photoGrid.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View v,
                    int position, long id) {

                // Sending image id to FullScreenActivity
                Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), SwipeActivity.class);
                // passing array index
                i.putExtra("id", position);
                startActivity(i);
            }
        });
        //end sent image to full screen

        // set image adapter to the GridView
        photoGrid.setAdapter(imageAdapter);

        // get the view tree observer of the grid and set the height and numcols dynamically
        photoGrid.getViewTreeObserver().addOnGlobalLayoutListener(new ViewTreeObserver.OnGlobalLayoutListener() {
            @Override
            public void onGlobalLayout() {
                if (imageAdapter.getNumColumns() == 0) {
                    final int numColumns = (int) Math.floor(photoGrid.getWidth() / (mPhotoSize + mPhotoSpacing));
                    if (numColumns > 0) {
                        final int columnWidth = (photoGrid.getWidth() / numColumns) - mPhotoSpacing;
                        imageAdapter.setNumColumns(numColumns);
                        imageAdapter.setItemHeight(columnWidth);

                    }
                }
            }
        });
    }

    // ///////// ImageAdapter class /////////////////
    public class ImageAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
        private LayoutInflater mInflater;
        private int mItemHeight = 0;
        private int mNumColumns = 0;
        private RelativeLayout.LayoutParams mImageViewLayoutParams;

        public ImageAdapter() {
            mInflater = (LayoutInflater) getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            mImageViewLayoutParams = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                    LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
        }

        public int getCount() {
            return CONTENT.length;
        }

        // set numcols
        public void setNumColumns(int numColumns) {
            mNumColumns = numColumns;
        }

        public int getNumColumns() {
            return mNumColumns;
        }

        // set photo item height
        public void setItemHeight(int height) {
            if (height == mItemHeight) {
                return;
            }
            mItemHeight = height;
            mImageViewLayoutParams = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, mItemHeight);
            notifyDataSetChanged();
        }

        public Object getItem(int position) {
            return position;
        }

        public long getItemId(int position) {
            return position;
        }

        public View getView(final int position, View view, ViewGroup parent) {

            if (view == null)
                view = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.photo_item, null);

            ImageView cover = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.cover);
            TextView title = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.title);

            cover.setLayoutParams(mImageViewLayoutParams);

            // Check the height matches our calculated column width
            if (cover.getLayoutParams().height != mItemHeight) {
                cover.setLayoutParams(mImageViewLayoutParams);
            }

            cover.setImageResource(ICONS[position % ICONS.length]);
            title.setText(CONTENT[position % CONTENT.length]);

            return view;
        }
    }

}
```

**SwipeActivity.java**

```
    package com.td.gridview;

    import android.app.Activity;
    import android.content.Context;
    import android.content.Intent;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.support.v4.view.PagerAdapter;
    import android.support.v4.view.ViewPager;
    import android.view.View;
    import android.view.ViewGroup;
    import android.widget.ImageView;



    public class SwipeActivity extends Activity 
    {   

      @Override
      public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.swipe_view);

     // get intent data
        Intent i = getIntent();

        // Selected image id
        int position = i.getExtras().getInt("id");

    ViewPager viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.view_pager);
    ImagePagerAdapter adapter = new ImagePagerAdapter();
    viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);
    viewPager.setCurrentItem(position);
  }

  private class ImagePagerAdapter extends PagerAdapter 
  {
      int[] icons = MainActivity.ICONS;    

    @Override
    public int getCount() 
    {
      return icons.length;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isViewFromObject(View view, Object object) 
    {
      return view == ((ImageView) object);
    }

    @Override
    public Object instantiateItem(ViewGroup container, int position) 
    {
      Context context = SwipeActivity.this;
      ImageView imageView = new ImageView(context);
//      int padding = context.getResources().getDimensionPixelSize(
//          R.dimen.padding_large);
//      imageView.setPadding(padding, padding, padding, padding);
      imageView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER_INSIDE);
      imageView.setImageResource(icons[position]);
      ((ViewPager) container).addView(imageView, 0);
      return imageView;
    }

    @Override
    public void destroyItem(ViewGroup container, int position, Object object) 
    {
      ((ViewPager) container).removeView((ImageView) object);
    }
  }
}
```

**activity_main.xml**

```
<GridView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/albumGrid"
    style="@style/PhotoGrid"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="@color/black"
    android:columnWidth="@dimen/photo_size"
    android:horizontalSpacing="@dimen/photo_spacing"
    android:numColumns="auto_fit"
    android:padding="4dp"
    android:scrollbars="none"
    android:stretchMode="columnWidth"
    android:verticalSpacing="@dimen/photo_spacing" />
```

**photo_item.xml**

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/album_item"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/cover"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/cover"
    android:background="#70000000"
    android:padding="6dp" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/title"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:ellipsize="end"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        android:textSize="12sp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />
</LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

**swipe_view.xml**

```
<android.support.v4.view.ViewPager xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/view_pager"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" />
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to retrieve your position in your Swipe activity like,

```
Intent n = getIntent();
int position= n.getIntExtra("id");
```

Now in your adapter

```
ImagePagerAdapter adapter = new ImagePagerAdapter(Swipeactivity Here , icons[position]);
viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);
viewPager.setCurrentItem(position);
```

UPDATE:

You need to change your adapter class. Like,

```
    private class ImagePagerAdapter extends PagerAdapter 
    {
      int[] icons;    
      Context c;

    public ImagePagerAdapter(Context ctx , int[] icons){

      this.c = ctx;
      this.icons = icons;

    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() 
    {
      return icons.length;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isViewFromObject(View view, Object object) 
    {
      return view == ((ImageView) object);
    }

    @Override
    public Object instantiateItem(ViewGroup container, int position) 
    {

      ImageView imageView = new ImageView(c);
//      int padding = context.getResources().getDimensionPixelSize(
//          R.dimen.padding_large);
//      imageView.setPadding(padding, padding, padding, padding);
      imageView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER_INSIDE);
      imageView.setImageResource(icons[position]);
      ((ViewPager) container).addView(imageView, 0);
      return imageView;
    }

    @Override
    public void destroyItem(ViewGroup container, int position, Object object) 
    {
      ((ViewPager) container).removeView((ImageView) object);
    }
   }
   }
```

NOTE: If you get error on Swipeactivity then import it.

Comment: may i ask 1 thing, can i pass my MainActivity class to context variable:

**like:**context=MainActivity

**so i can use it like this**
`ImagePagerAdapter adapter = new ImagePagerAdapter(Context , icons[position]);`

can i make **context = MainActivity class**

Comment: after changing code again got this:
`Description Resource Path Location Type
The constructor SwipeActivity.ImagePagerAdapter(SwipeActivity, int) is undefined SwipeActivity.java /Copy of TD GridView/src/com/td/gridview line 33 Java Problem
`

Comment: what the hell is actually wrong here i just want to get image position in my image swipe so image swipe start from selected image not from 1st image.

Comment: like when i show selected image view in full screen it was like
`// get intent data
        Intent i = getIntent();
 
        // Selected image id
        int position = i.getExtras().getInt("id");
        ImageView imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.full_image_view);
        imageView.setImageResource(MainActivity.ICONS[position]);`

but in viewpager it's not working

Comment: @user3739970 Go through this link. in which same as you want. http://www.androidhive.info/2013/09/android-fullscreen-image-slider-with-swipe-and-pinch-zoom-gestures/

Comment: i am not getting this tutorial code. there is too many thing in it and it reads image from sdcard not from drawable.

Comment: now i got this error:

`Description Resource Path Location Type
Swipeactivity cannot be resolved to a variable SwipeActivity.java /Copy of TD GridView/src/com/td/gridview line 32 Java Problem
`

`    ImagePagerAdapter adapter = new ImagePagerAdapter(Swipeactivity, icons[position]);
`